# No matching signature for operator > for argument types: FLOAT64,

Tags: where-clause

I have the follow syntax
select vendornumber,
Round(Sum(Freight),2) As Freight
From VendorInv
Where Dollars > '100'
AND Quantity <= '1000'
Group By VendorNumber
Order By Freight DESC

but i'm getting the follow error

"No matching signature for operator > for argument types: FLOAT64, STRING. Supported signature: ANY > ANY at [5:3]"

please help

I dont know what ton try. I am a new user of SQL